# What is the difference between Adobe Edge Code and Brackets?

Tags: html, editor, adobe, adobe-edge, adobe-brackets

Mainly, which is actually better? I want to know which one to use for production and what are the actual differences between them. I'm going to be using Bootstrap in them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of November 2014 **Adobe stopped further development of Edge Code** and recommends to switch to brackets.

Source: https://creative.adobe.com/de/products/code

Comment: I've updated this as the new correct answer, as this is the current state of things, thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Adobe Edge Code is a distribution of the Brackets open source project. It contains all the functionality of Brackets, plus additional extensions that integrate with other Adobe products like:

- [Edge Inspect](http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/)
- [Edge Web Fonts](https://edgewebfonts.adobe.com/)
- [Adobe Kuler](https://kuler.adobe.com/)

Edge Code uses the Creative Cloud desktop application to update in place. Brackets does not have an automatic update mechanism (yet).

As an open source project, Brackets releases new features more often, so there is a slight delay between when a feature lands in Brackets vs. Edge Code. Brackets also integrates with a central community-managed registry for browsing and installing extensions. Extensions must be manually installed into Edge Code.

Comment: Refer now to  @tschundee 's answer as this is the new correct state of things. Thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

**Edge Code is dead**. Adobe has stopped dev on it and recommends to switch to brackets.

Adobe edge code and brackets are both maintained by adobe. Edge Code is based on Brackets. If you are a Creative Cloud member, Edge is version is made special for you.

Here are some of the diffrences

1. You could call Brackets as the opensource and free where as Edge code is closed.
2. Edge code integrates well with adobe products where as Brackets does not do it out of box. Like this [adobe.com/....](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4712518)
3. Brackets is updates more frequently (2-3 weeks) where as Edge is not that frequent.
4. Brackets has a linux(debian based) support but i did not find a mention for Edge but they may.
5. Being closed you get support from Adobe for edge.

If you have a Adobe CC licence go for Edge else Bracket is awesome enough.

As for as your question goes for bootstrap you could use any thing even Notepad or GEdit. production or not either  doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Edge Code is not paid - it's also free. You just need to sign up for an 'Adobe ID,' which gives access to the free tier of Creative Cloud. No need for a paid membership.

Comment: I don't think Edge Code is supported on Linux, no.